# SQL triggers split with a constant and conditional

Tags: sql, triggers, relational-database, rdbms

I'm shooting in the dark here with this question, as I have very little database knowledge, but can RDBMS triggers be split with a constant AND a conditional, say, with multiple 'WHEN' statements in the same trigger? I was asked to research this topic, and quite frankly, do not even know where to begin outside of here.  I don't have any 'real' code to post, just looking for some theoretical insights from users with more database experience. Thanks in advance for the insight.

Sample Code:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER REORDER
 AFTER UPDATE OF ON_HAND, MAX_STOCKED ON PARTS
 REFERENCING NEW AS N
 FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (N.ON_HAND < 0.10 * N.MAX_STOCKED)
 BEGIN ATOMIC
 WHEN (N.ON_BCK_ORDR < N.CUST_ORDERED)
 VALUES(ISSUE_SHIP_REQUEST(N.MAX_STOCKED - N.ON_HAND, N.PARTNO));
 END
```

;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trigger can contain several 'WHEN' predicates when used within a CASE statement, as seen below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg
BEFORE UPDATE OF dept_salary
ON employee_wages

BEGIN
   CASE
      WHEN INSERTING THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting');
      WHEN UPDATING ('salary') THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATING SALARY');
      WHEN DELETING THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELETING');
   ENDCASE
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking. I think you need to know the create trigger syntax. Try to google for "create trigger" syntax for oracle, MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL database.